# Data Structure with O(log n) complexity for query

Tags: tree, time-complexity

Given database of customer find all the customers having a particular DOB. Which data structure will you use. O(logn) 
Map>m;
Find all the customers between  given DOB.  Pure O(logn)

I guess I am supposed to solve the same using a segment tree...
after creation of the segment tree...how am i supposed to find the particular DOB in that with O(logn) ... I can atmost get the lowest value of DOB within a range in that complexity with segment tree ...

what is the solution ?
also is there some other data structure i could use ?

Answer (score 0):

once you get the minimum dob with in given range use that DOB as Min DOB in Range and call your function again repeat this until you get all dates in that range .. :)